# basic HTTP authentication on subsequent requests

Tags: http, server, client, basic-authentication

The image below depicts basic HTTP authentication. The client requests `/family` resource and it is asked to identify itself. It does and now it can access the `/family`. The client then also asks for `/family/photos/kids` resource which is in the family realm.

The client already identified itself for `/family` resource, but not also for `/family/photos/kids`. They are in the same realm, but the server doesn't know that the same client issued a request. Or does it? How does the server know that this particular client is also allowed to access `/family/photos/kids` on subsequent request? Is the password and username send on every request after the user has authenticated? Is the client asked for via pop-up for every request he/she makes? Are cookies set upon first authentication?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic authentication requires a header sent by client. No cookies or server session

When the client requests a resource, sends the Authorization header

```
GET /family
Authorization: Basic token
```

Where token is base64(username: password). Username followed by ':' and password encoded in base 64

If you are requesting a protected resourced from your browser for example a GET request, and you do not provide the header, the browser shows the autenticathion form and remember it for subsequent requests in the same domain

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. So Authorization header along with base64 encoded credentilas are send on all subsequent requests to this whole domain or just /family? Will it send on /family/photos/kids too? Does the same happens with proxy authorization?

Comment: The client has to send the header in each request. If you use the browser to ask the user for credentials, will use them for the same domain. A proxy, such as Apache, can be used to manage authorization o pass up